# inconsistent scheduling (transactions..DBMS)

Tags: database

Initially the values of A=1000 , B=2000. When the first instruction of T2 executes ie read(A) will it read 950 or 1000? (Since write(A) is not performed before it)

```
T1           T2            
-------     --------
read(A)
A:=A-50
           read(A)
           temp: A * 0.1 
           A: A-temp
           write (A)
           read(B)


write(A)
read(B)
B:= B+ 50
write(B)


           B:=B +temp
           write(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most general case, it depends on what transaction isolation level you set, and how your dbms implements those isolation levels.

For example, the SQL standards say that dirty reads, nonrepeatable reads, and phantom reads are possible if you set the transaction isolation level to "read uncommitted". But in PostgreSQL, setting the isolation level to "read uncommitted" actually gives you the behavior of "read committed". (The SQL standards allow that; "read committed" is a stronger isolation level than "read uncommitted".)

The first instruction of T2 should read 1000, because

- the update in T1 hasn't been committed yet, and
- T2 is apparently using the server's default transaction isolation level, and
- it's very rare for "read uncommitted" to be set as the server's default transaction isolation level.

You can test this kind of thing in a database development environment by opening two  sessions. I use two terminal windows, myself.

You'd benefit from learning to think about databases in terms of transactions, isolation levels, commits, and rollbacks rather than in terms of reads and writes.